# Vue.js with Rails not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js

I am trying to send an AJAX call to Rails Controller to fetch some data and use Vue.js to output it. But it doesn't seem to be sending any kind of request to the Controller. What am I doing wrong here? Vue.js does work without AJAX call

*app/assets/javascript/calculator.js*

```
var calculator = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    numbers: []
  },
  ready: function() {
    var that;
    that = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/calculator.json',
      success: function(response) {
        that.numbers = response;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

*app/controllers/calculator_controller.rb*

```
class CalculatorController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @numbers }
    end
  end
end
```

*app/views/calculator/index.html.haml*

```
.container
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      %ul
        %li{ "v-for": "number in numbers" }
          {{ number }}
```

Comment: Some questions: Did you set out a Rails route for `get: '/calculator'? What do your server logs say is happening?

Comment: If server doesn't receive any requests, then are you sure a hook 'ready' fires? Which version of Vue.js are you using? Starting from Vue2.0 "ready" callback doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ready` try [**`mounted`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram):

```
var calculator = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    numbers: []
  },
  mounted: function() {
    var that;
    that = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/calculator.json',
      success: function(response) {
        that.numbers = response;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This did work! Could you explain why mounted works, but ready doesn't? From the diagram I assume mounted should always be used instead of ready?

Comment: Correct. Actually there is no such thing as ready. "mounted" is vue's "ready", informally stated.